# Unknown variable in interval comparison does not raises NameError

Tags: python, python-3.7

I faced a very weird issue today with this simple code:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

if var1 > var2 > var3:
    print('Does not run')

print('Did not crash')
```

Output:

```
Did not crash
```

Why isn't this code raising NameError with Python 3.7 ? Replacing the interval comparison with a simple comparison raises NameError as expected. Is this a python bug ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var1 > var2 > var3` is equal to `(var1 > var2) and (var2 > var3)`. First statement evaluates to `False`, so the second statement after the `and` is not evaluated at all because of [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).